# ASP.NET Web Farm with 4.0 and 4.5.1 causes Invalid postback or callback argument exceptions

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a site that runs in a web farm behind a load balancer. I have a consistent `<machineKey />` element in each of the web.config files on each of the servers. Until recently all servers ran .NET 4.0 (.NET 4.5 was not installed). This morning I introduced a new server to the farm that runs the exact same code and configuration as the existing servers, except it has .NET 4.5.1 installed.

I am using the following to target .NET 4.0 on all servers

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0">
```

And a machineKey element like this (key values removed for security):

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey decryptionKey="..." validationKey="..." />
</system.web>
```

Does .NET 4.0 handle validation or encryption/decryption differently than .NET 4.5.1 even when the targetFramework is 4.0?

Comment: This http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/10/23/cryptographic-improvements-in-asp-net-4-5-pt-2.aspx suggests that it should be backward compatible unless you turn on 4.5 mode in an explicit way.

Comment: I read it that way too, @WiktorZychla, but in our situation we didn't have the expected behavior. My next thought was to create a new machineKey element that explicitly specifies the validation and decryption methods and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every machine in a web farm must have the exact same version of ASP.NET installed.  Running 4.0 and 4.5.1 mixed in a farm is not supported.

That said, there are two ways to perform the upgrade:

1. Take half the farm offline, upgrade the offline machines to 4.5.1, then simultaneously bring these machines back into the farm while taking the remaining half offline.  Then update the remaining offline machines and bring them back in.
2. If you absolutely need to perform an in-place upgrade, set the <appSettings> switch *aspnet:UseLegacyEventValidationCompatibility* to "true" in Web.config ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440.aspx)), then one by one upgrade your machines to 4.5.1.  This is not a supported configuration but should work.  It is **imperative** that you not keep this <appSettings> switch around for any length of time, so be sure to remove it from your Web.config once the upgrade is complete.

Comment: I was wondering if this was even a supported thing that we were trying to do - thanks for the feedback, very helpful!

Comment: Any external reference to back up this?

Comment: Wiktor, back up what part in particular?  That mixed deployments aren't *officially* supported?  I'm from the product team, so I'm a primary source.  If you call customer support, they'll tell you the same thing, so that's perhaps external verification.

Comment: @Levi did reference an MSDN article as well that backs it up his comment.